# Allow authors to use their own Google Analytics code

Tags: google-analytics

Is it possible to allow multiple Google Analytics tracking code on one page? One for the website admin, and one for the author.

The purpose is to maintain website's main tracking code while allowing authors to insert their on tracking code to get stats of their own posts.

How can I do that?

Comment: What does the [Google Analytics support site](https://support.google.com/analytics/) say about allowing multiple tracking codes in a single page?

Comment: this is google aanalyics question and not a wordpress one, therefor off-topic. as @pat said you should go to google support for an official answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional tags for each author with their tracking code in a custom function.

```
is_author( '4' ) && is_single() )
```